# Linear Algebra - Understanding how to use the Gram Schmidt Orthogonalization Procedure

Tags: linear-algebra

Use the Gram Schmidt Orthogonalization Procedure to transform the basis $\{(1,2,1), (1,0,1), (3,1,0)\}$ into an orthogonal basis for $R^4$.

I haven't been able to understand how to use the Gram Schmidt Orthogonalization Procedure properly, I just couldn't grasp it during my lecture. If anyone could explain how to do this, that would be awesome!

Comment: Here's an excellent visual guide for what's going on: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Gram-Schmidt_orthonormalization_process.gif. You should watch it as you are trying to do it.

Comment: Well, you're sorta in trouble, cause none of those vectors are in $\mathbb{R}^4$ - they are in $\mathbb{R}^3$ (but do form a basis for $\mathbb{R}^3$). The essential idea is that given vectors $a,b$, you can split $b$ into a vector parallel to $a$, $b^{||}$ and a vector perpendicular to $a$, $b^\perp$. Gram schmidt greedily orthogonalizes by removing the parallel parts along the previous vectors you've already processed.